# How do I enable a particle system for text?

Tags: particles

I am using blender for the first time, and i am watching a tutorial to create an animated name, but when it was time to use the particles system, i didnt have the option enabled in my blender page, how can i install it or enable it on my screen?

Comment: Please add some screenshots to illustrate your question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to select a MESH object (particles do not work on curves or text).

To convert the text to a mesh, press Alt+C in Object mode, and select convert **Mesh from Curve/Meta/Surf/Text**

Then the options for particles will then be available in the Properties window.